How can I build a symmetric matrix of up to 100?
I have a square matrix of 100 elements in the form:
A = {{a^0, a^1, a^2, a^3,...,a^99}, {a^1, a^0, a^1, a^2,...,a^98}, {a^2, a^1, a^0, a^1,...,a^97}, {a^3, a^2, a^1,a^0,...,a^96}...{a^99,a^98,...,a^2,a^1,a^0}};
How can I write code for this matrix in Mathematica, so that I can change the order of the matrix, 2X2, 3X3, 4X4..., 100X100?
A2 = {{a^0, a^1}, {a^1, a^0}};
A3 = {{a^0, a^1, a^2}, {a^1, a^0, a^1}, {a^2, a^1, a^0}};
A4 = {{a^0, a^1, a^2, a^3}, {a^1, a^0, a^1, a^2}, {a^2, a^1, a^0, a^1}, {a^3, a^2, a^1, a^0}};
.
.
.
A100 = {{a^0, a^1, a^2, a^3,...,a^99}, {a^1, a^0, a^1, a^2,...,a^98}, {a^2, a^1, a^0, a^1,...,a^97}, {a^3, a^2, a^1,a^0,...,a^96}...{a^99,a^98,...,a^2,a^1,a^0}};

$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

ClearAll["Global`*"]

Using strings to hold your specified forms
mat[n_Integer?Positive] :=
 (a^ToString[Abs[#]] & /@ Range[1 - n, n - 1])[[n - # + 1 ;; -#]] & /@ 
  Range[n]

test = MatrixForm[mat[#]] & /@ Range[2, 5]


To convert the strings
test /. str_String :> ToExpression[str]


Your 100x100 matrix would be mat[100]

-1 for using string processing. This is bad advice, in my opinion.

@Roman — It wasn’t my advice, that is the form (e.g., a^0, a^1, …) that the OP requested. If you or they don’t want strings, just remove the ToString in the definition of mat

That's what Hold, Defer, etc. are for: see this guide on evaluation control. Using strings for evaluation control is bad advice, I think.

Look up a Toeplitz matrix:
m[n_] := a^(ToeplitzMatrix[n]-1)

Alternatively, an explicit construction as a rule-based matrix:
m[n_] := SparseArray[{i_, j_} -> a^Abs[i - j], {n, n}]

and the same with the explicit form requested:
m[n_] := SparseArray[{i_, j_} :> With[{d=Abs[i-j]}, Defer[a^d]], {n, n}]

m[4] // MatrixForm

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 a^0 & a^1 & a^2 & a^3 \\
 a^1 & a^0 & a^1 & a^2 \\
 a^2 & a^1 & a^0 & a^1 \\
 a^3 & a^2 & a^1 & a^0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Thank you very much

Maybe something along these lines:
SpecialMatrix[order_, symbol_Symbol] := 
  symbol^Take[NestList[RotateRight, Abs[Range[-(order - 1), (order - 1)]], order - 1], All, -order]

Demonstration:
A4 == SpecialMatrix[4, a]
(* True *)


Just a variant:
func[a_, n_] := 
 MapAt[Defer[a^#] &, DistanceMatrix[Range[n]], {All, All}]
(* examples *)
func[a, 3] // MatrixForm
func[x, 10] // MatrixForm



A simple method:
n = 3;
A3 = Table[Superscript[a, Abs[i - j]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}];
A3 // MatrixForm


